# A linux PDF reader that supports unicode characters

Tags: linux, fedora, pdf-reader

I use the default document viewer in Fedora. But for some languages such as *Persian* I can't copy texts. When I copy them and paste them somewhere, I get some irrelevant characters like `f! O I K Q- ! %%%v J; #" y`

How do I fix that?

Comment: How do you copy & paste? Does your "somewhere" support those character, i.e. are you able to enter the Persian characters there by some other means?

Comment: I paste them in Libreoffice writer

Comment: So, it's not really the reader problem? or? try to send it on google mail and open preview with it

Comment: @MurVotema Also tried gedit and gmail. The same result

Comment: Can you link to a sample PDF?

Comment: @choroba http://www.mediafire.com/?uu9bbknurney3u2

Comment: Strange. Cannot even Save as Text in AcroRead. The output contains garbage.

Comment: Could it be, that the problem occurs, because source document wasn't created with UTF-8? I think, it's not the reader problem, but the "problem" of the document